# Google cloud free trial payment error of [OR-ACH-04]

Tags: google-cloud-platform

To try Google Cloud, I would like to start the GCP free trial.

The problem is that in the registration process, it does not accept my payment and I cannot link a billing account to my Google Cloud.

I have a google pay profile with PayPal payment method and whenever I want to link my existing google pay profile to Google Cloud, I receive the following error:

*This action couldn't be completed. Try again with a different payment method. Learn more [**OR-ACH-04**]*

I should add this point that my google pay profile and this payment method is working with Google Drive without any problem and I already Subscribe to google drive with this payment method and bought extra google drive space.

The other point is that I do not have credit card and I only want to link my PayPal account to my google pay profile.

I would appreciate if someone could help me solve this error.

Best regards.

Comment: GCP is pickier about payment methods, because of the substantially larger bill you can run up. They likely want a real card on file.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be directed to GCP support.

Comment: I could not contact GCP support, so I asked this question here, hoping someone may help me. Contacting GCP support the online chat machine asks so many stupid questions and put me in a never ending loop, and after several hours of try I could not chat with a real person.

Comment: They will ultimately likely tell you the same thing I did; that you need a credit card on file.

Answer (score 4):

The error you're facing 'OR-ACH-04' is for an invalid account number. I believe the issue could be because the country or region where you're trying to setup the billing account, is not permitted to pay with a paypal payment method or there is another restriction linked to the paypal account.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/currency?authuser=0#filter-the-list) you have a list where you could see the currency Payment methods available for your region. Additionally, in [here](https://payments.google.com/u/0/paymentsinfofinder#) you could see all the possible regions and payment methods available (Just in case your region is not shown in the first link)

As mentioned by other members, the best would be to add a credit card to be able to set the account correctly.

Best,